# How to schedule different messages to be sent on a linux shared server

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm developing a tool for my company, that in very broad strokes is intended to message users some information (a link to a picture) if they decide they want to be notified when it comes online.

If it were just alerting them when it's online is easy, because you don't have to schedule it, just check the list to see if anyone wants to be messaged about the picture when it comes online, and do it.

But we also have "We've got your petition, the picture is not here yet but we'll message you when it is" kind of message, and a few "not here yet" that I have to launch days later if the picture isn't online yet. And all these scheduled jobs need to be canceled if in any moment the picture comes online, and we send the message with it's link.

I'll try to explain it in as much detail as I can:

1. The user asks to be notified
2. Our web takes note of the petition. (adds it to the DB)
3. Check if the file is already online. At this point in time the file might not have been uploaded yet, but may be mere seconds away from it. So if the picture is not online yet when the petition is made, we want to wait 1-2 minutes to send the "Picture not yet here" message. Just so we don't send a "not yet here" message and 5 seconds later a "here's your picture" one.
4. We want to wait a few hours (1-3), to send a new message asking them to be patient.
5. After another set amount of time (7 days, approx) we want to send a last message, letting them know that the picture might never reach them because it's not being uploaded.

In any given time, even after point 5, if the picture comes online we want to cancel all these schedules and send the message with the picture.

I've been trying to learn how to do this, and through my search I've learned of three possible ways to achieve this functionality:

**Option A:** A single Cronjob executing every minute, that sweeps the database table searching if it's time to send one of those messages.

This option is easy to understand, although I'm afraid it might tax the database too much. I can use the shifty control panel that 1and1 has to set up that single Cronjob and call it a day.

**Option B:** Programatically write Cronjobs for every message that gets scheduled.

This sounds like it would be more "efficient", or at least less taxing on the DB, but I'm not sure Cronjob is supposed to work like that. It's normally used to schedule tasks that repeat themselves, isn't it? This would need a whole lot of functions to work (read the Crontab, add a line, search a line, edit a line, delete a line). Problem being here that I don't know how to edit the crontab that's on 1and1 servers via php. I have tried to contact them but their support has not been helpful at all.

**Option C:** The "at" function in linux.
[This](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm) I just learned about. It looks like it would do what I want: schedule a task that happens only once, and it's structure seems pretty easy to handle. The problem here is threefold: 1- I don't know if PHP can execute Command Lines, 2- I don't know if the server at 1and1 has the "at" program installed, 3- I don't know if I can get a Command Line to execute a PHP file with the arguments to make it work.
And if any of these can be done, I don't know how.

As you see there are plenty of things I don't know about, but I've been trying to inform myself and learn. I just ask here because I'm at the end of the rope.

These options I listed are not an exhaustive list, they are just the methods I've found.

**Which method would serve my purpose better? And how to do it?**

**Relevant facts:**

- Our host and database are located within **1and1**, in a virtual server (meaning, we don't have a complete server for us, but share one with other clients)
- Although we have "Unlimited" database space and queries, there is still a hard limit of how many queries you can do in a certain limit.
- I'm new-ish to using linux, and I have not worked with PHP for years (until I've got this job!), so it would be better if your explanation doesn't assume deep knowledge on my part.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the question for formatting or grammar/orthography reasons, I did my best but it might not be enough. Also I am aware that this question might be "Too Broad" or "Opinion Based" depending on how the reader sees it, but asking only for each individual method without having the context of the whole question felt like "The XY Problem" to me. If you want to place it on hold for any of these reasons, don't hesitate, but please try to comment why, and I'm open to suggestions on how to improve it. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Just a heads up: questions beginning with "What is the best ..." are almost always off-topic. They often receive very opinionated answers and aren't of much use to future users.

Comment: @Loek thanks for the heads up. I really didn't pay as much attention to the title of the question itself as I should have. Do you have any suggestions to change it?

Comment: I would consider the same, @Loek, but here am I reading it again and checking both what deceze (moderator) wrote and the question, and I think he (Helwar) mainly added an off-topic title but with well described questions.

Comment: The answers won't really be opinionated when one option is *objectively* better...

Comment: But *objectively* better can be argued as *subjectively* worse considering how he have it implemented anyway, or not?

Comment: @Rafael ... ye-es but arguing against it would be like getting into a debate as to whether 2 + 2 = 4 ... or 5 or 7 - Orwellian distopia notwithstanding, there's only one *right* answer ;)

Comment: Yeah let's just say that this is that one in a million question that gets talked about on meta. The current highest rated answer is probably the best, plus it's very extensive. The question itself is rather large but pretty good, the title just instantly invites downvotes. @Helwar probably something along the lines of "How to use CRON to send multiple schedules messages?", however that still sounds somewhat shaky.

Comment: @CD001 ... I ... disagree, I don't think it's as simple as that. Much systems works(?) in very different ways and they might need an approach that is different than one that is used on a similar but not equal system anyway. But, anyhow, as I mentioned before, I like the question, maybe just the title is *specifically* off-topic. :)

Comment: @Loek what do you think of "How to schedule different messages to be sent on a linux shared server"?

Comment: Yeah that sounds pretty good. It covers the question well and is specific enough while it still allows some degree of opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Programatically write Cronjobs for every message that gets scheduled.

God no, the biggest issue you'll have with that is that you will have to anticipate in advance what kinds of messages you'll have to send when, and that clashes with your ability to easily cancel messages. You will generally have to worry about a lot of *state* to manage (more on that later), which is a lot of hassle. You also need to ensure your scheduled jobs are cleaned up again afterwards, since `cron` can only set repeating tasks.

> The "at" function in linux.

This is basically `cron` but for non-repeating tasks. That's better, but is still stateful. Especially with shared hosts it's also somewhat unpredictable whether your code will always execute on the same machine or when a machine might reboot. In those circumstances you may lose your scheduled jobs, so this is a no-go.

> A single Cronjob executing every minute, that sweeps the database table searching if it's time to send one of those messages.

Yes, this is the way to do it. The biggest advantage here is that it's *stateless*, in the sense that it will always pick up on the exact current contents of your database, so it allows you to easily manage what your job should be doing on its next run and not having to anticipate that at the time you schedule an event.

> I'm afraid it might tax the database too much.

It's *one* query per minute (if you write it well). Presumably every single page load of your website will incur one or multiple queries, and a properly built site should be able to handle hundreds to thousands of loads per second. One more query per minute isn't going to tank it. If it does, you have bigger issues.

Comment: doesn't this question qualify as off-topic since it's mainly opinion based? (Though I consider extremely pertinent and interesting which is why I upvoted both question and answers)

Comment: I think the options the OP gives can pretty clearly be evaluated (QED), so it's a very answerable question.

Comment: Makes sense. Will keep that in mind. Thank you. :)

Comment: I'd just like to add that if OP ends up using an online cron job service then the request becomes of Web and no longer CLI type, so settings like `max_execution_time` start to apply (which are usually set to 0 for CLI contexts)

Answer (score 1):

I would personally choose the option A, I'm using it already on a project I worked on.
In your case, having the data on a shared hosting, I would create a cronjob that runs every minute (using an [online service](https://cron-job.org/en/)) and hits a php file somewhere in your folders, checking in a database table if anything must be done.
You should write some code that handles all the notifications you want to send and when, creating, for each of them, a row in the db table with the time of execution and all the details ready to be used to create the notification and to send it out.

The entire thing would work more or less as follow:
- Something happens that requires the creation of a notification to be sent out in 5 minutes: the row is created in the db table with the unix time or date of 5 minutes from now.
- A notification needs to be sent out 3 days from now, you use the same procedure as above.

The cronjob runs every minute and checks for expired orders (anything with date <= now), if any, a script takes care of these rows and execute the orders (sending out only the notifications required).

The database wouldn't be bothered too much, having to perform only 1 query per minutes (only checking for expired orders).